# Superscript / Subscript buttons

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is just technical and mainly for the site developers. $\TeX$ does take up some resource I believe, and its usage should be limited to only those places where it is really necessary. Most of the times it is used only for subscripting in chemical formulae; it is much easier to write `$H_2O$` than writing `H<sub>2</sub>O`.

Is it possible to have subscript and superscript buttons in the formatting toolbar?

Comment: It should be on Meta.